# Hero Siege, how can we play on a more difficult setting?

Tags: hero-siege

I've noticed that "nightmare mode" exists, but we have only been able to play the intro stage (going back from the main City, so starting it from the end of the stage).

We've found no way to progress past that.

I guess it will be naturally be unlocked with a normal playthrough, but if we do that I'm afraid that the characters will also be of a level high enough to make it no longer challenging enough for our tastes.

Our goal is to increase the difficulty, that's why we were trying to play nightmare mode (~lvl 45) with lower characters (~lvl 15).

If this is not possible, but there are other "legit" ways to increase the difficulty which we haven't noticed, they would still be acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

You have to play through the game to unlock harder difficulties. There are 2 more after nightmare: hell and inferno. There's also a hardcore mode that permanently kills your character when you die.

Comment: Hardcore mode is irrelevant for this question, since the whole point is that we are overpowered and oneshot everything, so we never die, hence it doesn't change anything at all. I'm afraid that this answer doesn't really add anything to what I already knew: I'm searching for alternatives, these aren't :/

Comment: I also mentioned 2 higher difficulties you can unlock.

Answer (score -1):

In theory, you can just beat the final boss of the final act of each difficulty, which shouldn't level your character too much but also get you into the higher difficulties.